# floating header won't appear over image with hover

Tags: html, css

So I set up my header to fade with scroll, but appear with hover. It works over all the images, but the cat pictures in the Portfolio section. I adjusted the z-indexes and have tried everything. The header will not appear over the h4 or anything under the  The problem file is the portfolio.html. The header appears over the other pictures. It's been driving me crazy.
https://github.com/alil0rphan/Basic-Portfolio

```css
/* Eastablish body parameters */
body {
 background-image: url("../images/circlesbg.png");
 background-color: #D7CFC3;
 color: #777777;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/* Create Heading block */
h1 {
 background-color: #4AAAA5;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 25px 20px 0px 20px;
 height: 55px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 36px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
 font-weight: bold;
}
section {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
/*Establishes header on top */
header {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: solid 2px #cccccc;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 top: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
}
/* establishes tranparency on scroll */
body.scrolled #main-menu {
 opacity: 0.2;
 transition: opacity .2s;
 z-index: 98;
}
body.scrolled #main-menu:hover {
 opacity: 1.0;
 transition: opacity .2s;
 z-index: 97;
}
/* Makes sure heading and contents line up */
.banner {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
}
/* Navigational link parameters established */
.link-box {
 padding: 30px 0px 0px 20px;
 height: 55px;
 right: 0px;
 display: inline;
 position: absolute;
}
/* Establishes main content parameters (container and connect blocks) */
.content {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
/* Establish main unique block on each page */
.container {
 width: 590px;
 border: solid 2px #dddddd;
 float: left;
 margin: 115px 0px 200px 0px;
 padding: 30px;
}
/* Link attributes including hover */
a {
 color: #777777;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 word-spacing: 10px;
}
a:hover {
 color: #4AAAA5;
}
/* Establishing heading fonts  for container and connect box*/
h2 {
 color: #4AAAA5;
 font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 border-bottom: solid 3px #dddddd;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 32px;
}
h3 {
 color: #4AAAA5;
 font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #dddddd;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 24px;
}
/* adjusts line height and paragraphs for the about me section */
p {
 line-height: 2.5;
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin-top: 0px;
 color: #777777;
}
/* My picture on the index file */
#face {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 width: 250px;
}
/* Connections box parameters with icons */
.connect {
 width: 210px;
 border: solid 2px #dddddd;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 115px;
 padding: 30px;
}
/* Establish icon aesthetics and behaviors with hover features */
.icons {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px 5px 30px 0px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}
.icons:hover {
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #4AAAA5;
}
/* cat pictures and parameters established with hover features*/
.cats {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px 40px 40px 0px;
 width: 230px;
}
.cats:hover {
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #4AAAA5;
}
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   display: inline-block;
}
/* establishes parameters for banners over the cat images */
h4 { 
   position: absolute; 
   width: 230px;
   background-color: #4AAAA5;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: 50px;
}
/* Establishes sticky footer */
footer {
 background-color: #666666;
 opacity: 0.85;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: solid 6px #4AAAA5;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 color: #BFBEBC;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.clearfix::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}
/* Establishes input attributes for the contact/ message form. */
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px; 
    border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    resize: vertical
}
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4AAAA5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* Makes the Submit button change color when mouse hovers over */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: #666666;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
label {
 color: #8F7E7F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<div id="main-menu">
 <header>
  <div class="banner">
   <h1>John Bendfeldt</h1>
<!-- Navigational links. -->
   <div class="link-box">
    <a href="index.html">About | </a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Porfolio | </a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</div>
<body>
 <div class="content">
<!-- Big content box in middle -->
   <section class="container">
   <h2>Portfolio</h2>
   <br>
<!-- Images for the main content block -->
   <div class="image">
    <img src="assets/images/cat1.jpg" class="cats" alt="kitten">
    <h4>Building Websites</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="assets/images/cat2.jpg" class="cats" alt="kitten">
    <h4>RPG</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="assets/images/cat3.jpg" class="cats" alt="kitten">
    <h4>Trivia Game</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="assets/images/cat4.jpg" class="cats" alt="kitten">
    <h4>Rock Paper Scissors</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="image">
   <img src="assets/images/cat5.jpg" class="cats" alt="kitten">
   <h4>American Freedom</h4>
   </div>
  </section>
<!-- connect with me box -->
  <section class="connect">
   <h3>Connect with Me</h3>
   <br>
   <a href="https://github.com/alil0rphan" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/Github-icon.png" class="icons" alt="Github-icon" title="GitHub"></a>
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-bendfeldt-b32736130/" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/linkedin-icon.png" class="icons" alt="linkedin-icon" title="LinkedIn"></a>
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/7700030/john-bendfeldt" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/stackoverflow-icon.png" class="icons" alt="stackoverflow-icon" title="Stackoverflow"></a>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
<footer>
 © Copywrite 2017 John Bendfeldt
</footer>
<!-- makes the header transparent on scroll -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   document.body.classList[
    window.scrollY > 20 ? 'add': 'remove'
  ]('scrolled');
});
</script>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add a `position: absolute;` in `body.scrolled #main-menu` selector. It will look like this:

```
body.scrolled #main-menu {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index: 98;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It won't let me accept the answer yet. Do you know why that worked?

Comment: Do not worry, you can accept the answer later :). The opacity property with a value less than 1 will cause the navbar to be positioned below tags with an opacity of 1. With an absolute position, the navbar will be raised over tags with a lower z-index.